# How to upgrade existing project from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I want to upgrade my existing Laravel project (a web with Laravel 5.3) to Laravel 5.5 because Laravel 5.3 have different structure than 5.5. If will upgrade all my files will be automatically follow there new directory or I have to made changes to my files to work properly.

Comment: All the useful sources are mentioned below. In case you have a huge application with lots of code, you can leverage Rector https://github.com/rectorphp/rector to speedup process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually depends on your project size, since the estimated upgrade duration is `1-2 Hours`, you might simply wish to copy almost all your files (one by one of course) to a newly installed Laravel 5.7, since it's the current latest version. Otherwise you should do it for every version by following the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade

I usually copy my files over to a new project if the project is small.
Otherwise I simply follow the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps:

1. open composer.json file and change the version 5.3 to 5.5 and also upgrade the PHP version to at least 7.0
2. Delete composer.lock file
3. Delete Vendor Folder
4. Open Terminal and run the command (composer update).

Comment: On my case, I used composer install. I believe composer update will update all packages to last version?